# Add onclick to Image Tag

Tags: html, click, graphical-logo

This line displays my logo:

```
<li><img class="logo" src="selector/logo.png" alt="" /></li>
```

How can I add a clickable link to this image?

Answer (score 2):

Try this here:

```
<li>
   <a href="target.html">
      <img class="logo" src="selector/logo.png" alt="" />
   </a>
</li>
```

You want properly also to remove the border around the image. To fix that use this CSS:

```css
.logo {
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just asking how to make the image a hyperlink to itself?  Like this?:

```
<li>
  <a href="selector/logo.png">
    <img class="logo" src="selector/logo.png" alt="" />
  </a>
</li>
```